# Use java files on kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to make an app that can detect smiling and blinking from the front camera using firebase MLkit. Unfortunately, i couldnt find an in-depth tutorial of how i could achieve this, i found a working git project though its java and i;m wondering if i could just use it in our kotlin project.

here is the git project
https://github.com/ankitjamuar/android-firebase-mlkit/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit

Comment: Do you use android studio? If yes I know how to do this

Comment: Kotlin would be pretty bad if it couldn't work with Java libraries (including the Android Framework)

Answer (score 0):

Java and Kotlin are fully interoperable. You shouldn't encounter any problems. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin compiles runs on JVM platfrom as well as utilise a lot of existing java libraries. Therefore short answer is yes - you can import java libraries and add .java files to kotlin project. You can find more information java kotlin interpretor in official kotlin documentation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is a language that is fully interoperable with java. If you understand the differences between the two languages, you can convert any java code into a kotlin code.

Intellij also gives you a nice utility to convert Java into Kotlin. If you face issues, we are here to help.